# Keycloak nuget packages for C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, keycloak

Is there any updated and usable library of Keycloak for ASP.NET, last time I wanted to implement Keycloak to my web api application, and I got suprised by the lack of support for this, even in the same Keycloak documentation the only library recommended for C# is out of support.

I'm asking this mainly because I wanted to have a runner to configurate a Realm from the C# code, just like Java has its own, and it can be implemented in this way:

```java
 RealmRepresentation realm = new RealmRepresentation();
    realm
        .setRealm("MyRealm")
        .setEnabled(true);
```

I could use the Keycloak's REST API by doing the HTTP calls manually but this won't be the same as when you have a library.

Comment: `this won't be the same as when you have a library.` the libraries use the REST API too. If you have the API's OpenAPI specs you can create a client too. In any case, what you posted isn't an API call, it's how Java handles the lack of properties. In C# you'd write `var realm=new RealmRepresentation { Realm="MyRealm", Enabled = true};`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this https://github.com/fschick/Keycloak.RestApiClient? I'm not sure it is like Java's one but it can help you.